# How to associate two tables without association table?

Tags: mysql

It's currently i am using .In that i want to reduces the association table .And attain the same objective.Kindly some one help me to find solution.

```
 CREATE TABLE sys_student_t (
 student_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 student_name VARCHAR(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
);

 CREATE TABLE sys_classrooms_t (
  classroom_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  classroom_name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (classroom_id)
 );

 CREATE TABLE student_classroom_association_t (
  association_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  classroom_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  student_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES sys_student_t (student_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (classroom_id) REFERENCES sys_classrooms_t    (classroom_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (association_id)
 );
```

Here is fiddle link :- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ada4fd/2
thanks

Comment: Did not understand what you try to do.

Comment: @ juergen I want to associate two tables without association table. Is there any option available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Many-To-Many" relationship will always require an additional table. The only thing you can do is changing the primary key of the association table to the pair `student_id` and `classroom_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE student_classroom_association_t (
  classroom_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  student_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES sys_student_t (student_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (classroom_id) REFERENCES sys_classrooms_t    (classroom_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id, classroom_id)
 );
```

Comment: @MurugesanM I'm pretty sure this is a good start: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561